# Panel grid layout or stretch panel?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jspx

I'm creating a page based on a template to present a query with results table and when i select a result the same data as to be presented on the side as a form.
I have tryed to do it inserting a panel grid layout with some cells, so each cell will have the query form, another to the results table and other details that i have to insert.
This is the basic layout:
[image]

When i change the cell poperties so i can see the table and everything else, one of two things happen, the table fills all the page (width) or it stays very small and i have to use the scroll bar to see all the data. What i want is that the table use all the width available in the cell.

Can someone help me doing this with a grid layout or is there another way, such as a stretch layout that i can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just use two nested stretch layouts, will give you good and clean result.

```
<af:panelStretchLayout>
  <f:facet name="top">
    <!-- fixed size header -->
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="start">
    <!-- fixed size menu -->
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="center">
    <af:panelStretchLayout>
      <f:facet name="top">
        <!-- search form -->
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="end">
        <!-- right block -->
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="center">
        <!-- table -->
      </f:facet>
    </af:panelStretchLayout>
  </f:facet>
</af:panelStretchLayout>
```

Don't forget to set stretching option for components that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that menu and header are part of a template which you are using in your page, here is one way to achieve your layout structure

```
- panelStretchLayout
    - facet name="center" 
        - panelGroupLayout (layout="vertical" styleClass="AFStretchWidth") 
            - search form
            - panelStretchLayout (endWidth="100px" dimensionsFrom="auto")
                - facet name="center"
                    - table ( columnStretching="last" styleClass="AFStretchWidth")
                - facet name="end"
                    - form
```

Comment: Uh-oh, avoid doing such things. Don't put stretch containers into flow containers.

Comment: Thanks @Nagh for pointing out the mistake. I do not need to correct it now as you have already answered it with the right approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your cells? Set the first and last cell width to a fixed size.
Then the middle cell should have the halign=stretch.
From the doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_gridCell.html

This component can stretch a child component if (1) it is the only component inside of the gridCell, (2) the cell's "halign" is "stretch", (3) the cell's "valign" is "stretch", (4) the effective width of the cell is non-auto, and (5) if the effective height of the cell is non-auto.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using panel grid layout, ADF improved panel grid layout component in version 11.1.2
An ADF application normally starts with a stretchable outer layout container that stretches its children so make the outer layout panel grid with a 100% height row and 100% width 

The benefit of panel grid it matches the way HTML tables are laid out, so it offers good performance compared to other ADF layout components.